# Incorrect number format when value is < than 0

Tags: c#, format, devexpress

I have a DevXpress grid display some information about geolocalization this including Longitude and Latitude, both columns are formated as Number `"N5"` but in latitude I have 45,xxxx and in latitude I have `-73,xx` I double checked generated code and DevXpress `"WYSIWYG"` but can't find anything.

The generated code:

```
// 
// colLatitude
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.colLatitude, "colLatitude");
this.colLatitude.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N5";
this.colLatitude.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
this.colLatitude.FieldName = "Latitude";
this.colLatitude.MinWidth = 50;
this.colLatitude.Name = "colLatitude";
this.colLatitude.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
this.colLatitude.OptionsColumn.AllowGroup = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.colLatitude.OptionsColumn.AllowSort = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.colLatitude.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
```

```
// 
// colLongitude
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.colLongitude, "colLongitude");
this.colLongitude.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N5";
this.colLongitude.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
this.colLongitude.FieldName = "Longitude";
this.colLongitude.MinWidth = 50;
this.colLongitude.Name = "colLongitude";
this.colLongitude.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
this.colLongitude.OptionsColumn.AllowGroup = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.colLongitude.OptionsColumn.AllowSort = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.colLongitude.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
```

code from the view's controller :

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Get la Latitude
 /// </summary>
 public double Latitude
 {
   get { return this.GPSEventData.Latitude; }
 }
 /// <summary>
 /// Get la Longitude
 /// </summary>
 public double Longitude
 {
   get { return this.GPSEventData.Longitude; }
 }
```

Comment: have you tried setting the format type to `DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom`?

Comment: Actualy, no because the format is good when > 0

Comment: This may just be a typo in your question, but you say that you are seeing one of the values as 45,xxxx.  It only has 4 x's. If the formatting is working for numbers > 0 I would expect it to display as 45,xxxxx (5 x's), so maybe < 0 has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the grid is bound to a datasource somehow, such as a `DataTable`.

Check the types of `Latitude` and `Longitude` in the datasource. If they are defined as `string` the formatting in the grid will not work.

Your values of  45,xxxx and -73,xx are formatted with commas, which makes me think they might be defined as string in the datasource.

If you're actually using the commas as a decimal mark, it might have something to do with localization settings.  Take a look at this post: [How to fix an application that has a problem with decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428670/how-to-fix-an-application-that-has-a-problem-with-decimal-separator)

Comment: I Edited my post with the code from the controller. both value are Double.

Comment: I'm at a loss to think of anything else.  I tried applying French culture specific settings and it worked for me. I assume that's what you are using - "Get la Latidtude" :-)

Comment: One other thing.  You could try setting the cell value yourself using `gridView1.SetRowCellValue(1, "colLatitude", -73.12345);` If that works you could at least narrow it down to only a problem with the bound values from the controller.